# Delete row and column in spreadsheet without using drive api

Tags: android, google-sheets

I am not using Google Drive Api instead ,I am using the below method to upload data into my spreadsheet am successfully able to show data of each row and column in my app .Now the biggest challenge am facing is how to delete a row or column data could anyone tell me a idea on how to do it .Below is my code.

For Retreive data Below code

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, View.OnClickListener {

ProgressDialog pd;
private  String[] board_size = {"Select Your Size", "8 x 6 ft", "10 x 8 ft", "12 x 8 ft", "12 x 10 ft", "16 x 10 ft", "16 x 12 ft", "20 x 10 ft", "22 x 10 ft", "24 x 12 ft", "30 x 10 ft", "40 x 10 ft", "50 x 10 ft", "60 x 10 ft", "70 x 10 ft", "80 x 10 ft"};

 ListView lstv11;
 ArrayList<AshTable> array111;


SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

private Button bt1;
private Button bt2;


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,
            container, false);



    array111=new ArrayList<>();

    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);


    lstv11=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lst_vw1);

    bt1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.but_add);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(this);






    getActivity().runOnUiThread(  new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new HomeFragment.ReadJSON().execute("https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxx);
        }
    });



    return view;


}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {

    array111.clear();

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(  new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new HomeFragment.ReadJSON().execute("https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxx");
        }
    });
}


public class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return readURL(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String content){

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(content);
            JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("BaseAshTable");

            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject prdobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String test1 = prdobj.getString("Timestamp");
                String test2 = prdobj.getString("Company_Name");
                String test3= prdobj.getString("Person_Name");
                String test4 = prdobj.getString("Address");
                String test5 = prdobj.getString("Mail_ID");
                String test6 = prdobj.getString("Mobile_1");
                String test7 = prdobj.getString("Mobile_2");
                String test8 = prdobj.getString("Show_Name");
                String test9 = prdobj.getString("Dispatch_Date");
                String test10 = prdobj.getString("Dispatch_Time");
                String test11 = prdobj.getString("Start_Date");
                String test12 = prdobj.getString("Start_Time");
                String test13 = prdobj.getString("Setup_Date");
                String test14 = prdobj.getString("Setup_Time");
                String test15 = prdobj.getString("Show_End_Date");
                String test16 = prdobj.getString("Show_End_Time");
                String test17 = prdobj.getString("Dismantel_Date");
                String test18 = prdobj.getString("Dismantel_Time");
                String test19 = prdobj.getString("Venu");
                String test20 = prdobj.getString("Venue_Address");
                String test21 = prdobj.getString("Board_Size");
                String test22 = prdobj.getString("Overall_sqft");
                String test23 = prdobj.getString("Rate_Per_Sqft");
                String test24 = prdobj.getString("Total_Amount");
                String test25 = prdobj.getString("Transport");
                String test26 = prdobj.getString("Stage");
                String test27 = prdobj.getString("Power");
                String test28 = prdobj.getString("Other_Costs_1");
                String test29 = prdobj.getString("Other_Cost_2");
                String test30 = prdobj.getString("Gross_Amount");
                String test31 = prdobj.getString("Bill_Required");
                String test32 = prdobj.getString("Company_Name");
                String test33 = prdobj.getString("Billing_In_Name_Of");
                String test34 = prdobj.getString("Service_Tax");
                String test35 = prdobj.getString("Total_Amount_2");
                String test36 = prdobj.getString("Advance_Amount");
                String test37 = prdobj.getString("Credit_Period");
                String test38 = prdobj.getString("Photographer_Name");
                String test39 = prdobj.getString("Photographer_Mobile");
                String test40 = prdobj.getString("Photographer_Email");
                String test41 = prdobj.getString("Marketing_Person_Name");
                String test42 = prdobj.getString("Remarks");


                array111.add(new AshTable(test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8, test9, test10, test11, test12, test13, test14, test15, test16, test17, test18, test19, test20, test21, test22, test23, test24, test25, test26, test27, test28, test29, test30, test31, test32, test33, test34,test35,test36,test37,test38,test39,test40,test41,test42));

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final CustomListViewAdapter adapter=new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.home_list_view, array111);
        lstv11.setAdapter(adapter);


        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

    }

}




private static String readURL(String theUrl) {

    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content.toString();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == bt1) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),Submit_form.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (v == bt2) {



    }


}
```

}

After implementing below is the screenshot how it looks 
[image]
Now what I need is how to delete each list view in my app on doing so the spreadsheet should also get updated.Please help .Thanks